# Can we get secret value from azure without using client secret?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-secrets

I am doing like this :

```
   ClientSecretCredential cred = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantId, ClientId, ClientSecret);
   SecretClient client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(KeyValutURL), cred);
   string ConnectionString = client.GetSecret(ColumnInfoSecretName).Value.Value;
```

Here I am getting connection string with ClientSecret but I want to get secret without using clientsecret.

Comment: What are you running your app on? Managed Identities are a good option if that is supported in the platform.

Comment: I am doing it on .Net Core MVC and I am trying with DefaultAzureCredential but it shows this type of error "DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token".

Comment: Yeah but are you running it locally or on Azure App Service or on Azure Kubernetes Service or something else?

Comment: We are using Azure App Service.

Answer (score 2):

You would need some kind of credentials to connect to and get data from an Azure KeyVault. `ClientSecretCredential` is one of the available credentials.

For the list of all available credentials, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet

[image]